# (re)Populating mongodb collection from json - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi is there a way to repopulate a mongo collection from a json array using mongoose?

I have this schema.

```
var UserNote_Schema = new Schema({

user_id: {type:ObjectId, ref:require('../User/User_Schema.js')},

note: {type:String},

created: {type:Date},

last_mod: {type:Date}

});
```

and would like to populate it with this json and have it save to the collection.

```
   {"_id":"506b8922a6bd97d322000011",
"user_id":"504aaeef898f541527000012",
"note":"a note","created":"2012-03-10T00:38:58.000Z",
"last_mod":"2012-03-10T00:38:58.000Z"}
```

My goal is to reset my database to a certain state after running some tests which add remove and change some of the data within.
However, if there is more convenient way of achieving a database reset from a previous state in mongoose/mongo I'd much appreciate any pointers. Keeping the versioning info would also be nice.

thanks

Comment: Not much to it; just iterate over your json array and update each document by `_id` to the json value.  What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Thanks, some of the items could of been deleted during the tests so what I want to do is empty the collection and repopulate it.

Comment: It works fine, if I just create a model and call save. The only  caveat seems to be that the _v field is always set back to 0. Sorry to waste your time. I'm used to fighting with databases and thought it'd be more difficult :) thanks for putting me on the right track.